# In JSP is it necessary to redeclare tag libraries in included files?

Tags: jsp, include, taglib

Im not really familiar with how this works in JSP

but in the

main.jsp template there is this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/common_head.jsp"/>
```

then in common_head.jsp we have this again:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
```

is this necessary?

or in other words

**Are taglib declarations propagated to include files?**

Comment: the included files are never used "standalone", they are always included. you never access common_head.jsp directly since it generates the <head></head> content of the main html file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is necessary. Before executed for the first time, every JSP file will individually be converted/translated/compiled to a standalone `Servlet` class. All tags will be translated to "real" Java code/methods. If you don't declare a taglib, then the JSP compiler don't know what Java code/methods it need to generate/call for the particular tags.

In case of for example Tomcat, take a look in the `/work` folder for all of those compiled JSP's. View their source and it'll be all clear.

Answer (score 4):

The

```
<jsp:include page="/jsp/common_head.jsp"/>
```

... tag is a dynamic include meaning that it dynamically calls the common_head.jsp page, which is compiled independently of the including page. Thus the taglib directive should be needed.

If, on the other hand you were to do a static include using the include **directive**

```
<%@ include file="/jsp/common_head.jsp" %>
```

... the file would have been **copy-pasted** and and compiled with the page from which it is included. Then the taglib directive should not be needed.

In any case you may want to have the taglib included just to get editor support of the tags you use during development.

Note that static files are statically included, even with the jsp:include tag

include directive: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref129.html#997991

jsp include: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1214.html

Answer (score 2):

As you're including a dynamic resource, that resource is "standalone" so it should include any tag library that you are using. Other question is if you're using those tags...

Comment: ok, but the included files are never used "standalone", they are always included. you never access common_head.jsp directly since it generates the <head></head> content of the main html file

Comment: yes, but your usage does not affect how should be declared it. The JSP file is compiled whenever you access it, so when common_head.jsp is compiled, it should have declared all the tags it needs.

Comment: see this comment:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200112.mbox/%3CHEEPJJNMMLODBABODAGJGEKFCDAA.ctucker@epangea.com%3E

if you use instead <%@include ... />, then you would not need to redeclare them, as it is "inserted" in compile time

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is required for JSP compilation .
You can also use below taglib instead of c.tld.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

hope this will help

Answer (score -3):

In other template systems the definitions usually carried over. I dont see why you should have to use it again

Comment: -1 This answer is incorrect. One of the other three answers (all of which are correct) ought to be accepted in its place.